# dnorm and dmvnorm results not matching

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I noticed the substantial difference between the values returned from dmvnorm (mvtnorm package) to dnorm (baseR). Which one is the correct result and why? In case of independent normal random variables, which one should I use?

```
> mvtnorm::dmvnorm(rep(1,2),rep(0,2), diag(2,2))
[1] 0.04826618
> prod(dnorm(rep(1,2),0,2^2))
[1] 0.009344515
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `dmvnorm`, you specify covariance; for `dnorm`, you set standard deviation. So if you feed `diag(2,2)` to the former, you want `sqrt(2)` to the latter.

```
prod(dnorm(rep(1,2),0,sqrt(2)))
# [1] 0.04826618
```

Comment: this is a good answer.  are you willing to replace "u" with "you" in your answer to make a grumpy old guy happy?